# Packagemanager is corrupted

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, kubuntu, dpkg

Everytime when I try to update my OS it returns these error messages:;

```
patrick@Lappy:~$ LANG=ENG
patrick@Lappy:~$ sudo aptitude upgrade
[sudo] password for patrick: 
Warning: Invalid locale (please review locale settings, this might lead to problems later):
  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
The following partially installed packages will be configured:
  initramfs-tools linux-firmware linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic 
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.    
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = "en_US:nl",
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LANG = "ENG"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.6) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-firmware (1.187.25) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-41-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/plymouth failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-41-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--configure):
 installed linux-firmware package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic (5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.6) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-41-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/plymouth failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-41-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic (5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.11.0-41-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-41-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/plymouth failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-41-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-firmware
 initramfs-tools
 linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.6) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-firmware (1.187.25) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-41-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/plymouth failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-41-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--configure):
 installed linux-firmware package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic (5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.6) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-41-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/plymouth failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-41-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic (5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.11.0-41-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-41-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/plymouth failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-41-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-firmware
 initramfs-tools
 linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic
```

So there is something with Plymouth and

linux-firmware
installed linux-firmware package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1

initramfs-tools
installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1

linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic
installed linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1

Is there anyway to repair this, or should I make a list of my installed software and reinstall everything. I would be not to happy to reinstall because my laptop charger is broken, so I have to work on battery and have to charge with a freaking mobile charger through the USB3  port, so that would take days.

I already tried this:
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
but obviously that didn't work! ( If it did I would not ask this fine community for help. )

Can anybody help me find a cure for this problem, or do I really have to reinstall ( so shortly before a new LTS is released )?
I run:
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.7
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.11.0-41-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-10510U CPU @ 1.80GHz
Memory: 15,3 GiB
On HP Envy i7 CE000ns in tripleboot with Mint 20.2 Uma and Win10 ( seperated OS's and /home partitions, swap partition and win10 and 'my documents'partition ).

Thanks in advanvance for sharing your time and knowledge. I really appreciate it.

edit 220112 at 22.04h local spanish time
although my system is set to english\american, the output in the terminal is in dutch. See screenshot:[image]. How can I change this? So I can edit the question.

Comment: Add `LANG= ` (with space at the end) before the command to force the output to English.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat did LANG=ENG and it worked. I'll edit my question.

Comment: @Nmath, thanks, I edited my question. Although ctrl+K didn't work, the ``` did. (Finally figured that one out.)

Comment: Maybe try `sudo apt install --fix-broken plymouth`?  Or maybe just reinstall plymouth?

Comment: @ Bovine fixing the broken plymouth didn't work. Purged it and installed it again. Got no more errors. So this fixed it. Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I purged Plymouth and installed it again with 'aptitude'. Then I typed  `sudo aptitude upgrade` and it upgraded 29 packages without any errors. Thank you all for your time and help.